# LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: база-данных, mysql, файлы, sql

Хочу записать даные из текстового файла в БД.

Такой запрос работает:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'D:/file.txt'
INTO TABLE products(barcode);
```

И такой тоже:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'D:/file.txt'
INTO TABLE products
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

А такой **нет**:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'D:/file.txt'
INTO TABLE products(barcode)
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Выдает:

> SQL Error (1064): You have an error in
> your sql syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server
> version for the right syntax to use
> near 'FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'  LINES
> TERMINATED BY '\n'' at line 3

*Как записать данные только в заданные поля таблицы?*

Comment: А где Вы нашли такой синтаксис с скобками?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А так будет работать?

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'D:/file.txt'
INTO TABLE products
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (barcode);
```

Comment: Благодарю.